# How to use Perl's Text::Aspell to spellcheck a text?

Tags: perl, spell-checking, aspell

I want to add spell checking to my Perl program. Looks like [Text::Aspell](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Aspell) should do what I need, but it only offers a function to check single words.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Aspell;

my $input = "This doesn't look too bad. Me&you. with/without. 1..2..3..go!";
my $aspell = Text::Aspell->new();
$aspell->set_option('lang', 'en');
print "$input: ", $aspell->check($input), "\n";
```

This prints:

```
This doesn't look too bad. Me&you. with/without. 1..2..3..go!: 0
```

So clearly it does only take single words, then how do I separate a text into words? A simple `split` at white space:

```perl
foreach my $word (split /\s/, $input) {
    next unless($word =~ /\w/);
    print "$word: ", $aspell->check($word), "\n";
}
```

This gets problems with punctuation marks that don't have white space:

```
This: 1
doesn't: 1
look: 1
too: 1
bad.: 0
Me&you.: 0
with/without.: 0
1..2..3..go!: 0
```

I guess I could mention the punctuation characters:

```perl
foreach my $word (split qr{[,.;!:\s#"\?&%@\(\)\[\]/\d]}, $input) {
    next unless($word =~ /\w/);
    print "$word: ", $aspell->check($word), "\n";
}
```

This gets reasonable output:

```
This: 1
doesn't: 1
look: 1
too: 1
bad: 1
Me: 1
you: 1
with: 1
without: 1
go: 1
```

but seems clumsy and I'm wondering if there is an easier (less code for me to write, less brittle) way.

How do I spell check a text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Text::Aspell` has no options to check a whole string, and instead only checks single words. Instead of splitting the string by yourself, I would suggest to use a module that already does that for you, such as [`Text::SpellChecker`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::SpellChecker). For instance:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::SpellChecker;
use feature 'say';

my $input = "This doesn't look too bad. Me&you. with/without. 1..2..3..go!";
my $checker = Text::SpellChecker->new(text => $input);
$checker->set_options(aspell => { 'lang' => 'en' });

while (my $word = $checker->next_word) {
    say "Invalid word: $word";
}
```

Or,

```
my $checker = Text::SpellChecker->new(text => $input);
$checker->set_options(aspell => { 'lang' => 'en' });

if ($checker->next_word) {
    say "The string is not valid.";
} else {
    say "The string is valid.";
}
```

The [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::SpellChecker#SYNOPSIS) of the module shows how you could interactively replace erroneous words:

```
while (my $word = $checker->next_word) {
    print $checker->highlighted_text, 
        "\n", 
        "$word : ",
        (join "\t", @{$checker->suggestions}),
        "\nChoose a new word : ";
    chomp (my $new_word = <STDIN>);
    $checker->replace(new_word => $new_word) if $new_word;
}
```

If you want to check each word of the input string individually yourself, you could have a look at how `Text::SpellCheck` splits the string into words (this is done by the [`next_word`](https://metacpan.org/dist/Text-SpellChecker/source/lib/Text/SpellChecker.pm#L278-295) function). It uses the following regex:

```
while ($self->{text} =~ m/\b(\p{L}+(?:'\p{L}+)?)/g) { 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Following code snippet uses regex which doesn't include letters and `'` to split a sentence into a words.

You can *extend* regex how your heart desires.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Aspell;

my $regex = qr/[^'a-z]+/i;
my $input = "This doesn't look too bad. Me&you. with/without. 1..2..3..go!";
my $aspell = Text::Aspell->new();

$aspell->set_option('lang', 'en');

printf "%12s: %d\n", $_, $aspell->check($_) for split($regex, $input);
```

Output

```
        This: 1
     doesn't: 1
        look: 1
         too: 1
         bad: 1
          Me: 1
         you: 1
        with: 1
     without: 1
          go: 1
```